# automatically gathering multiple variables with same name into an array

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python program which reads a word and its meanings (one or more) from a json file and creates audio for each meaning separately.

As a result there are dynamically generated  multiple audio files such as `M-1.mp3`, `M-2.mp3`, ... `M-n.mp3`

later on i want to concatenate all the audio files into one audio clip with a function which requires the names of each  audio files listed one by one.

Is there a way i can pass the filenames as a list to the function provided that I know the number of audio files that I want to concatenate.

I want something like this:

```
One_Audio=concatenate(listnames("M-",3))
```

to get the this:

```
One_Audio=concatenate("M-1.mp3","M-2.mp3","M-3.mp3")
```

effect.

Comment: ``concatenate(*(f"M-{n+1}.mp3" for n in range(0, 3)))``?

Comment: to pass the prefix, use "{prefix}{n+1}.mp3" here (assuming you name it `prefix`)